# Incompatibility error installing CUDA on Windows

Tags: windows, cuda, installation, gpgpu, nvidia

I am on Windows 8.1 Pro and I want to install CUDA 5.5. I have installed Visual Studio 2013 already and I have the latest GPU driver's version 335.23. In the NVIDIA control panel I have also set CUDA - GPUs to GeForce GT 740M. My CPU is Intel Core i7 4700MQ which comes with an Intel HD 4600 GPU.

When I click on the setup.exe file it shows me an error as follow:

"This graphics driver could not find compatible graphics hardware. You may continue installation, but you will not be able to run CUDA applications."

I also performed a clean installation of the latest stable driver, but still I cannot install CUDA.

[image: Visual Studio Not Found]

What should I do?

**Update1**: Turns out that the bundled NVIDA graphics driver in CUDA 5.5 is older than the one installed on my computer. So I continued the installation without asking CUDA to install the graphics driver on my computer. But now the following error is shown.

**Update2**: Neither CUDA 5.5 nor CUDA 6.0 RC support Visual Studio 2013. I had to install VS 2012 and the issue is resolved now

Answer (score 4):

The graphics driver in the CUDA 5.5 installer pack is not compatible (too old) with the GT740M.

Go ahead and install CUDA without installing the driver that comes with the CUDA 5.5 installer.  In fact I would select the custom install option and just uncheck the driver install.

Your 335.23 driver is fine and is compatible with CUDA 5.5

Comment: I have Visual Studio 2013 installed on my computer. But CUDA's installation window is showing me an error saying it cannot find Visual Studio installed on my computer! I will add the picture to the question now.

Comment: So this is a new question and new problem, right?  It's better to ask new questions using a new SO question.  VS2013 is not an [officially supported compiler for CUDA 5.5](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-toolkit-release-notes/index.html#windows-5-5).  Probably there is a how-to on the web somewhere of someone who has tried to get it working anyway, but I won't be able to help you with that.  My recommendation would be to switch to a supported version of VS.